# How to compute RMSE for TBATS

Tags: r, forecasting, tbats

Some forecasting models in R give error terms as their output. But for TBATS, I couldnt find out that how I can see what the RMSE for my data set is. Is there any specific command that I have to use to get this value? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you look at what `tbats` returns, you will see `variance` as one component. So

```
fit <- tbats(x)
rmse <- sqrt(fit$variance)
```

will give you the RMSE.

But even if you weren't sure what that component contained, you can always compute RMSE directly from the residuals of any model:

```
res <- residuals(fit)
rmse <- sqrt(mean(res^2))
```

You can also use the `accuracy` function:

```
fc <- forecast(fit)
accuracy(fc)
```

Comment: Thank you Dr Hyndman. I knew how to compute it myself but thought there might be a specific command for that. Thanks

Comment: TBATS output does not include variance (May be Im intrepreting it wrong) but there is a parameter named sigma which I believe is RMSE. Am I right?

Comment: The above code works. variance is part of the object returned by `tbats`. You are confusing what is produced by print() with what is returned by tbats().

Comment: The `str` command is highly undervalued. Apply it to any object to get detailed information.